# Probability of 8 bit binary string whose first three bits are 001, 010, or 100.

Tags: probability

A bit unsure of how to approach the following question.

Consider the uniform probability space where the set of outcomes consists of all 8-bit binary strings.  What is the probability of each of the following events?

a) The first three bits of the string are 001, 010, or 100.

I calculated the total number of 8 bit string sequences to be 2^8 or 256.

Now, do I calculate the probability of the first three digits being a particular sequence in the following way :

Pr["001"] = .5 x .5 x .5 = .125 or 32 sequences
Pr["010"] = .5 x .5 x .5 = .125 or 32 sequesces
Pr["111"] = .5 x .5 x .5 = .125 or 32 sequences

Pr[001 or 010 or 111] = (32 + 32 + 32)/256 = .375

I feel I might be doing something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are correct, but you could have done this problem a lot more easily. You note that each bit is independent of the next, so you can just take the space of all 3 bit strings, and find the probability that a given one is one of the three you've chosen. That immediately gives you $\frac38$.

Answer (score 1):

We have three chances of getting the first three bits with a single one out of the $2^3$ possibilities. That's $\frac{3}{8}$. Then we have $2^5$ combinations for the remaining five bits but they don't matter because, for every value they may have, there is still the $\frac{3}{8}$ chance that the leading digits will have one one. Answer: $\frac{3}{8}= 0.375$ so you got it right.